# read() hangs while watching for event0 using inotify

Tags: inotify

I am in need to use /dev/input/event0 to be watched for key events.I have used inotify_add_watch(), but the read() call hangs.But If I cat /dev/input/event0 I can see some events.Please let me know what is wrong.Below is my code snippet

/*creating the INOTIFY instance*/
        fd = inotify_init();

```
    /*checking for error*/
    if ( fd < 0 ) {
            perror( "inotify_init" );
    }
    /*adding the /dev/input/event0 to watch list.*/
    wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/dev/input/event0", IN_ALL_EVENTS);
    if (wd < 0){
            perror("inotify_add_watch");
            exit(-1);
    }
    for (;;) {
    length = read(fd, buffer,EVENT_BUF_LEN);
    printf("length = %d",length);
            if (length == 0)
                    perror("read() from inotify fd returned 0!");

            if (length < 0)
                    perror("read");
     printf("Read %ld bytes from inotify fd\n", (long) numRead);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained why you think you need to use inotify for this.
I'm assuming that you just want to programmatically test whether an event is ready.

You can do something like:

```
int fd = open("/dev/input/event0", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
struct pollfd pfd; // see man 2 poll
pfd.fd = fd;
pfd.events = POLLIN;
if (poll(&pfd, 1, &ts, 1000 /* milliseconds */) > 0) {
   // reading from fd now will not block
}
```

This will wait for up to 1 second (1000 milliseconds) for an event to be ready to read.  You can change the timeout to whatever you need.  You can also use 0 to test whether there is data available immediately without waiting.

Answer (score 0):

read() is a blocking function and waits for file update, unless specifically mentioned.
If you want it to be non-blocking, simply add a flag.
file_descriptor = inotify_init1(IN_NONBLOCK);
https://linux.die.net/man/2/inotify_init1